Restrict customers to buy once per year In WooCommerce
I'm using this coding to restrict the users to create an order per year, and it's working well. But, I noticed that if the date created of the last order is more than 365 days, the coding takes it as it was from this year so it doesn't let users that have purchased with more than 365 days to buy again. Can someone please review the coding and make the necessary modifications? Thanks in advance!
function new_order_allowed() {
    if( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) return;

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        $last_order = wc_get_customer_last_order( $user_id );

        if ( $last_order ) {
            $date_created = $last_order->get_date_created()->format( 'z' ) + 1;
            $current_time = current_time( 'z', true ) + 1;
            $year_in_day = 365;
            $days_passed = $current_time - $date_created;

            if ( $days_passed < $year_in_day ) {
               wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<b>ONLY ONE PURCHASE IS ALLOWED WITHIN 365 DAYS. </b><br>Your last order was %1$s days ago. Please try again when the 365 day period has been reached. ',  $days_passed ), 'error' );

                remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout','woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'new_order_allowed' );



I fixed the error and now it works, here is the final coding in case someone needs it:
function new_order_allowed() {
    if( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) return;

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        $last_order = wc_get_customer_last_order( $user_id );

        if ( $last_order ) {
            $date_created = $last_order->get_date_created()->format( 'U' );
            $current_time = current_time( 'U', true );
            $year_in_sec = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
            $seconds_passed = $current_time - $date_created;
            $last_order_created = $last_order->get_date_created()->format( 'M d, Y' );  

            if ( $seconds_passed < $year_in_sec ) {
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<b>ONLY ONE PURCHASE IS ALLOWED WITHIN 365 DAYS. </b><br>Your last order was on %1$s. Please try again when the 365 day period has been reached. ', $last_order_created, $day_in_sec, $seconds_passed ), 'error' );
             remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout','woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'new_order_allowed' );


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Why you not do it in a simple way?
$dateFrom = new DateTime($last_order->get_date_created()->getTimestamp());
$dateTo = new DateTime();
$dateTo->modify('-1 year');
echo $dateFrom->diff($dateTo)->days;

That way $dateFrom->diff($dateTo)->days; will return for you the quantity of day between both dates.

if I add the date as you suggest it, I will need to update it manually in the future

You not need to put date manualy:
I adjust the answer without manually date.

it gives a critical error message
